# Grails Domain class association with stored procedure resultset

Tags: mysql, grails, stored-procedures, view, gsp

Hi All,

Is it possible to associate the resultset of a stored procedure to grails domain class...?

I got this database view mapped to an domain class, which works like a charm, but in a typical functionality i need to generate db view based on certain parameters given by the end user. In that case i cant pass parameters to db view, so i created a stored procedure which would give me the same resultset as view but after calculations involving multiple table & getting parameters from end user.

In grails views (list.gsp) most of the plugin that i use is based on domain class , for ex: filterpane. 
So i cant just simply display the resultet from stored proc into grails

I am a newbie to grails. I have gone through grails froums, googled alot but unable to get any suggestions in this  topic.

Comment: Amit, not quite sure what we have to work with here. Can't you use a "findBy(xyz)" in your domain classes?

Whenever I need to do what it sounds like you're wanting to do I create a domain class called XXXReport with the fields that I'm interested in, then thanks to quartz I schedule it to run however often I want it to.

Comment: @marko, as i said i have a db view which is mapped to a domain class,  selecting records from different tables. Now i need to do some internal logic based on input values, lets say start date & end date given by the end user. so the list to be constructed based on internal logic rather than db view. For this i've created db stored proc. now my prob is how to associate the resultset that i'll from stored proc. with the view which is mapped to grails domain class..

Comment: sorry for the late reply, did you manage to solve anything?

Answer (score 1):

Grails provide [transient fields](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) to use when you need calculation fields in domain classes. You can wrap your calculation logic in a service, changing your domain class instances before using it.

```
class MyDomain {
  BigDecimal calcField

  static transients = ['calcField']
}

class MyService {
  def dataSource

  List<MyDomain> getInstances() {
    def instances = MyDomain.findAllBy...()
    instances.each { MyDomain ins ->
       doCalcField(ins)
    }

    instances

  }

  void doCalcField(MyDomain myDomain) {
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    //call procedure, returning values as OUT
    myDomain.calcField = calcField //assign out to domain instance
  }

}
```

Depending on your calculations, it's better to do it in the service directly, making your code database independent.

Comment: Sérgio thanks for reply, with above suggested code we can apply internal logic/calculations to domain objects, but in my case i've mapped db view to domain class & as you know views are nothing but simply selecting records from different tables. Now with my logic in stored procedure i'll get resultset dynamically just like view. But how can i map this to my domain class instead of mapping directly to db view...? As you have suggested i cant populate the domain objects & later do the calculations, since the creating domain objects itself dynamic.

Comment: basically i am trying map a list of objects from a service/method to domain class & it **should not** be saved in database, so that the logic in controllers/views  remains unchanged. Is it even possible....?

Comment: @Amit If you change only transient fields Grails will not try to update them in the database.